# Solve $12Q-20- 144/Q^2 = 0$

Tags: polynomials

I don't know how to find $Q$:

$$12Q-20- \frac{144}{Q^2} = 0$$

Comment: Try a few numbers.  Start with factors of 144.

Comment: Multiply on both sides by $Q^2$ to get $120Q^3- 20Q^2- 144= 0$, a cubic polynomial equation.  Divide through by 4 to simplify: $30Q^3- 5Q^2- 36= 0$.  Use the "cubic formula".  Or you could check to see if there are rational roots- if there is a rational root, Q= m/n, then the numerator, m, must evenly divide 36 and the denominator, n, must evenly divide 30.

Answer (score 14):

\begin{align}&12Q-20-\frac{144}{Q^2}=0 &\times Q^2\\   
&12Q^3-20Q^2-144=0 &:4\\   
&3Q^3-5Q^2-36=0 \end{align} 
Use rational root theorem which leads you to find $p=\frac{m}{n}$ where $m$ must divide $36$ and $n$ must divide $3$ and $p$ must be integer
$p=3$
then divide whole equation by $(Q-p)$

$$(Q-3)(3Q^2+4Q+12)=0$$
equation $3q^2+4q+12=0$ has ${4^2}-{4*3*12}=-128<0$ so that the only real solution is

$$Q=3$$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Your answer would be better if you stated you used Rational Root theorem, and for the $12-144<0$, stating that you used the discriminant $b^2-4ac$ would help increase the clarity of the solution.

Comment: Amazingly polite comment.

Comment: In addition, $Q=3$, is the 'only Real solution' not just the 'only solution'.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}0=12Q-20-\frac{144}{Q^2}=\frac{12Q^3-20Q^2-144}{Q^2}\iff 3Q^3-5Q^2-36=0\end{align} or $Q^2(3Q-5)=36$. Now, you can write $36$ as $$36=2^2\cdot3^2$$ so since $Q^2$ (could) divide $36$, two reasonable numbers to test first are $Q=2$ and $Q=3$. Indeed $Q=3$ is a solution and the only real one.